# How to add url to bookmark?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, bookmarks, qtwebkit

I am using PyQt4 for creating a custom browser using QtWebKit, but I am stuck on saving bookmarks from the browser. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You're a little vague on how you want this done, so I'll say we wanted to use a button imported from a UI file called `bookmarks_Btn`. You'll need to use the `pickle` module.

Here's the example code...

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit, uic
import pickle

class window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(httpWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('mybrowser.ui')
        self.ui.setupUi(self)      

    def bookmarksLoad(self):
        print 'Loading bookmarks'
        try:
            bookOpen = open('bookmarks.txt', 'rb')
            bookmarks = pickle.load(bookOpen)
            bookOpen.close()
            print bookmarks # Not necessary, but for example purposes

            # Here you decide how "bookmarks" variable is displayed.

        except:
            bookOpen = open('bookmarks.txt', 'wb')
            bookmarks = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
            bookWrite = pickle.dump(bookmarks, bookOpen)
            bookOpen.close()
            print bookmarks # Not necessary, but for example purposes

            # Here you decide how "bookmarks" variable is displayed.

     QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.bookmarks_Btn, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.bookmarksLoad)
    self.ui.show()

def bookmarks():
    url = input 'Enter a URL: '
    bookOpen = open('bookmarks.txt', 'wb')
    bookOpen.write(url)
    bookOpen.close()
    print 'Website bookmarked!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    run = window()
    bookmarks()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# You add on here, for example, deleting bookmarks.
```

However, if you wanted it to be retrieved from an address bar (named `address`, make the following changes...

```
# In the bookmarks function...
global url # Add at beginning
# Remove the input line.

# Add at end of __init__ in window class:
url = self.ui.address.text()
global url
```

That's pretty much the basics. Please note I normally program in Python 3 and PyQt5 so if there are any errors let me know :)